# When writing a synopsis "review", may I contact the authors with questions?

Tags: publications, mathematics, ethics, review-databases

Please read the following background paragraph carefully to understand the meaning of "review" in this question - it may not be what you think.  In particular, this is not a duplicate of [Is it acceptable as referee to contact an author on a paper you review?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9523/is-it-acceptable-as-referee-to-contact-an-author-on-a-paper-you-review), and the [peer-review](/questions/tagged/peer-review) and [review-articles](/questions/tagged/review-articles) tags are not really applicable here.

In mathematics, we have two well-known "review databases": [MathSciNet / Mathematical Reviews](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/) and [Zentralblatt MATH (aka zbMATH)](https://zbmath.org/).  These services aim to create a comprehensive database of papers that have **already been published** in peer-reviewed journals.  For each recently published paper, they invite an independent expert in the subject (not one of the authors) to write what is (perhaps confusingly) called a "review", which is really just a **synopsis of the paper's content** - a sort of third-party extended abstract, perhaps 1-4 paragraphs long.  The review is generally ***not* expected to make a judgment of the paper's quality or novelty**, though it may cite other papers for context.  When the review is finished, it is posted in the database along with bibliographic information for the paper, **including the reviewer's name** (so these reviews are not anonymous).  The databases are available by subscription, and are the field's primary tool for literature searches.

---

I have been invited to review a paper for zbMATH.  In reading the paper, I got confused by some notation that seems to be unclear; it could be an error or omission in the original paper, or maybe just something I have overlooked.   I would like to contact the authors to ask for clarification.  **Is it appropriate for me to contact them directly?**  If so, should I identify myself as a zbMATH reviewer, or just a reader with a question?

I can't think of any concrete reason not to do so.  My review will eventually be printed with my name, so I don't have anonymity to protect, and it won't say anything controversial.  But I do have some vague sense that my review is supposed to be "independent", so I am hesitating.

I suppose I can ask the zbMATH editors / administrators, but I would also be interested in opinions from the community.

(Note that the database editors are not generally in contact with the authors of the paper - they just grab the published papers and send them out to reviewers.  So it isn't as though I would use the editors as an intermediary.)

---

For reference, the invitation from zbMATH reads as follows:

> [W]e would like you to contribute a review of the attached item for
>   zbMATH. We hope that you will find the publication to be of interest to
>   you. We would appreciate if your review would give an independent
>   description. If you cite parts of the original text please label
>   extensive verbatim quotations as such.

More information about what is expected in a review can be found at https://zbmath.org/reviewer-service/, but the issue at hand is not addressed.

Comment: I am fairly sure that the "independent" in "independent description" means textually independent, i.e., not copying from the source and reasonably selfcontained. (I would contact the author without hesitation. Then again I am not a ZB/MathSciNet reviewer.)

Answer (score 10):

I contacted the zbMATH editors with this question, and received the following reply from staff member David Biesenack:

> It is totally okay, if
>   you contact the author for clarification.

Answer (score 6):

I have written almost 100 Zentralblatt reviews and contacted authors numerous times for clarifications. In one case, the author forgot to include part of a proof, which I put into the review for him. Usually it's just some notation I don't understand. I think there is no problem contacting the author and in fact the author may appreciate it.